# Populating an Array in a Document Class

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, flash-cs6

I'm trying to make a quiz with 4 buttons for the multiple choice answers. After you select an answer it plays a short animation and takes you to the next question. I was doing it all in time line code but have learnt since that AS3 is better suited to OOP using class files so I'm trying that now.

I thought rather than make 1 frame per question I'll make 1 frame for all the questions and populate the question caption and the answer buttons from arrays. I originally defined the array in an "Action Script" layer but now i've decided to do it in a class file called DocumentClass.as. My unfinished code so far is thus:

```
    package {
import flash.display.MovieClip;


public class DocumentClass extends MovieClip
{
//global definitions
private var milanquestions:Array = new Array();
private var milancorrectanswers:Array = new Array();
private var userscore:Number = 0;
private var currentquestion:Number = 0;

milanquestions[0] = "What is the primary type of Rescue used?";
milanquestions[1] = "Why is Remote Lower the preffered method to use?";
milanquestions[2] = "Which pieces of equipment are needed to complete a Rescue safely?";
milanquestions[3] = "Who conducts the Rescue?";
milanquestions[4] = "Once the casualty reaches the ground, what is it important to do first?";
milanquestions[5] = "What is used to keep the casualty clear of any obstruction?";

milancorrectanswers[0] = "Remote Lower";
milancorrectanswers[1] = "It can be done without another operative needing to climb down to the casualty";
milancorrectanswers[3] = "A Balfour Beatty operative trained in Tower Rescue";
milancorrectanswers[4] = "Place in the recovery position and administer first aid where possible";
milancorrectanswers[5] = "A holding out rope";

public function DocumentClass()
    {
        //a place for listeners
    }
  }
}
```

Using this code I'm getting the following error on each entry in to the arrays:

```
P:\Interactive Animation test folder\DocumentClass.as, Line 13  1120: Access of undefined property milanquestions.
P:\Interactive Animation test folder\DocumentClass.as, Line 14  1120: Access of undefined property milanquestions.
```

etc.

I wish to populate the arrays with questions and correct answers but I can't seem to get around these errors. Any ideas? Or any suggestions on better ways of doing what I'm trying to do?

Comment: Try to put the array assignment in some function, and call the function in the contructor

Comment: Like I said, I've been using Action Script and Flash less than a day and I'm not a programmer by trade. Any answers are going to have to be a little less vague and more descriptive.

Answer (score 0):

```
public class DocumentClass extends MovieClip
{
     //global definitions
    private var milanquestions:Array = new Array();
    private var milancorrectanswers:Array = new Array();
    private var userscore:Number = 0;
    private var currentquestion:Number = 0;

    public function DocumentClass()
    {
    //a place for listeners
         initAnswerAndQuestions();
    }

    private function initAnswerAndQuestions():void {

        milanquestions[0] = "What is the primary type of Rescue used?";
        milanquestions[1] = "Why is Remote Lower the preffered method to use?";
        milanquestions[2] = "Which pieces of equipment are needed to complete a Rescue safely?";
        milanquestions[3] = "Who conducts the Rescue?";
        milanquestions[4] = "Once the casualty reaches the ground, what is it important to do first?";
        milanquestions[5] = "What is used to keep the casualty clear of any obstruction?";


        milancorrectanswers[0] = "Remote Lower";

        milancorrectanswers[1] = "It can be done without another operative needing to climb down to the casualty";
        milancorrectanswers[3] = "A Balfour Beatty operative trained in Tower Rescue";
        milancorrectanswers[4] = "Place in the recovery position and administer first aid where possible";
        milancorrectanswers[5] = "A holding out rope";
    }
}
```

Comment: Excellent thank you. Is that how you call a function then? Just name it? And I assume the location if it's not within the same class?

Comment: yep, calling a function is just `myFunctionName();`, granted it is in the same class.